# Facebook live friend search fql problems

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I have a few problems with friend search. I am developing app which posts something to select friends wall. I am using the JavaScript SDK to login and gain permissions.

My init function:

```
FB.init({
                appId: 'xxxxxxxxx',
                status: true,
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true,
                oauth: true});
```

Login function:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse){
                        //if loged in
                    }else{ 
                       //if canceled
                    }
                }, {scope: 'publish_stream'});
```

After this I am using input which id is search with jQuery for friend live search:

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
        $("#friends").load("draugai.php",{
            "search":$("#search").val()
        }, function(){
            $(".friend").click(function(){
                $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
            });
        });
    });
```

my php file uses fql for friend search:

```
   require_once('facebook.php');

$config = array(
    'appId' => 'XXX',
    'secret' => '1234',
    'cookie' => true
);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
try {
    $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo($e->getType());
    echo($e->getMessage());
}

if ($_POST['search'] != "") {
    $search = strtolower($_POST['search']);
    $fql = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND strpos(lower(name),'$search') >= 0 ORDER BY name";
} else {
    $fql = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY name";
}
if ($user_id) {
    try {
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api(array(
            'method' => 'fql.query',
            'query' => $fql,
                ));
        foreach ($ret_obj as $value) {
            echo "<div class=\"friend\" uid=\"" . $value['uid'] . "\">";
            echo $value["name"] . "<img src=\"" . $value['pic_square'] . "\"/>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo($e->getType());
        echo($e->getMessage());
    }
} else {
    echo "no user";
}
```

I have a few problems with this app:

- I can't get this to work on Google Chrome. When I use Firefox everything works nice, but when I trying it on Chrome php file prints "no user". It acts the same if I don't login at all.
- Another problem is that this live search works very slow. It sends respond after 5-6 seconds. How can I increase search speed? At first I fought to use request dialog, but I only want to select one user.

Comment: Just a note - one should **NEVER** post application secrets, access tokens, app_ids, etc... With that information someone could impersonate you, your application or your page and perform some malicious actions. I have removed the sensitive data from your post. Please be aware of this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).  It uses the (very familiar) dropdown for friend selection ( your users will undoubtedly be familiar with that ).  And you can leave the friend searching to Facebook
You have already demonstrated that you can the JavaScript SDK to call the login method so calling the [`FB.ui()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) method should be fairly straigh forward.  Here is a code sample from the Facebook documentation I have linked to above.

```
var obj = {
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
  picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
  name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
  caption: 'Reference Documentation',
  description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
};

function callback(response) {
  document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
}

FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

From within the `callback` function you can detect that a post was made successfully by checking to see that a `post_id` parameter is present.

---

Just let Facebook help you out!
 [A little bird once told me](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/03/get-me-the-laziest-people-money-can-buy.html) that [good programmers are always the lazy ones](http://cade.datamax.bg/away/docs/little-lazy-programmer.gif). ;)

Comment: I saw this opportunity earlier, but it isn't good for my application, because at first i need to select friend and then choose what to post on his wall.

Comment: Ok...well... in that case you might want to pre-fetch the users friends and store them in your database - then for the autocomplete query your own database.